# How to layout HTML elements relative to bottom?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to layout 3 elements in react (without jQuery and bootstrap). See the image:

[image: Page Layout]

Essentially, the application has a container div that takes 100% height of Body, which is set to window height. It has three child elements:

- Header: Positioned relative to the top of container
- Footer: Positioned relative to the bottom of container; may have variable height
- Contents: Positioned relative to the top of footer

Getting container and header in place is easy but footer and contents are the difficult pieces. My code looks something like this:

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
}

#footer: {
  position: fixed,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  left: 0,
}
```

I am trying to understand best way to achieve it. Can you please suggest how should I write CSS?

Comment: What is reactjs tag for ?

Comment: Some of this is being implemented in react. I just extracted styles out of it to make it simple for one that knows HTML/CSS but not reactjs.

Comment: @RahilParikh you can use jquery in which you can subtract height of header and footer the remaining can be provided to content section

Comment: @AnmolSandal It is recommended that one doesn't use jQuery and Bootstrap for UI changes as it interferes with ReactJS.

Comment: Do you want your header and/or footer to scroll with the content or to be fixed?

Comment: @jaxx The content will always be fixed. However, footer is further divided in 3 sub-containers and depending on screen-size they may either be stacked in a column or in a row.

Comment: Oh so regardless of the window size, the content will always fit? How do you guarantee that? Or do you have minimum width & height in mind? Sorry, trying to understand.

Comment: The pages use minimalistic design/content so the user won't need to scroll in many cases. Also, `contents` div could also have minimum height/width attached to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  flex: 0 0 120px;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

footer {
  flex: 0 0 10%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WZKwEb

Explanation: The layout uses CSS3 flexbox. All elements have a different background color to give visual feedback of proportions and heights.

The top level container div is the flexbox container. Its height and width are set to 100vh (100% viewport height) and 100vw (100% viewport width) respectively.

The header and footer are set to specific heights (the header in pixels, the footer in %, for the sake of demonstrating both), while the content div is set to occupy the remaining space, and grow or shrink accordingly (`flex: 1 1`).

If the contents of the header or footer overflows their specific heights, their height will be adjusted accordingly, at the expense of the content div. The content div has its overflow set to `hidden`, meaning its content will neither overflow into the header or footer, nor cause a scrollbar to appear, instead the overflowing content will just be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the updated answer. Hope it is helpful to you. Kindly review the answer. Here i first calculated the height of header and footer and window height and provided remaining height to content by subtracting height of header and footer from it. Jindy review the jquery code. Hope that is helpful to you.

```js
var WindowsSize=function(){
    var h=$(window).height(),
        w=$(window).width();
        headerHeight = $('.header').height();
        footerHeight = $('.footer').height();
        h=h-headerHeight-footerHeight;
    $(".content").height(h);
};
$(document).ready(function(){WindowsSize();}); 
$(window).resize(function(){WindowsSize();});
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="header">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    test
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### This is how you can do with plain css vey less code

https://codepen.io/bhupinderkumarbl/pen/LzBGZN

```
.content {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content:space-between
}
h1, h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

<div class="content">
  <h1>heading 1</h1>
  <p>Some text more or less</p>
  <a href="/" class="button">Click me</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Super clean and simple code below which is fully flexible also.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.container{
  min-height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
section, header, footer{
  background:#EEE;
  padding:20px;
  border:5px solid #FFF;
  text-align:center;
}
section{
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>Header</header>
  <section>Content</section>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```